# Problem with QuickSort algorithm causing Maximum Call Stack

Tags: javascript

So, I have a program that calls the function : doQuickSort that takes the array i want sorted. I used a quicksort algorithm and everything seems fine to me but when returning the Partitionindex at the bottom of the Partition function I exceed the stack calls. If anyone can help me that would be great.

```
const animations = [];

export const swap = (arr, current, next) =>{

    animations.push(arr[current]);
    animations.push(arr[next]);

    var curVal = arr[current];
    arr[current] = arr[next];
    arr[next] = curVal;
}

export const doQuickSort = (array) => {
    var run = 0; 
    
    if(run == 0){
        QuickSort(array, 0, array.length-1);
        run++;
    }

    function partition(array, start, end){
        let pivot = array[end];
        let partitionIndex = start;
        
        for(let i = start; i < end; i++){
            if(array[i] <= pivot){
                swap(array, i, partitionIndex);
                partitionIndex++;
            }
        }

        swap(array, partitionIndex, end);
        partitionIndex++;

        return partitionIndex;
    }

    function QuickSort(array, start, end){
        if(start < end){
            let partitionIndex = partition(array, start, end);
            QuickSort(array, start, partitionIndex-1);
            QuickSort(array, partitionIndex+1, end);
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not really understand your "*partitionIndex++;*" before the "*return partitionIndex;* " inside the *partition* method. IMO that is your problem. OK your animations array inside the swap method also is bizarre for me. You probably have your reason for it.

But try this by the way:

```js
const animations = [];

const swap = (arr, current, next) =>{

    animations.push(arr[current]);
    animations.push(arr[next]);

    var curVal = arr[current];
    arr[current] = arr[next];
    arr[next] = curVal;
}

const doQuickSort = (array) => {
    var run = 0; 
    
    if(run == 0){
        QuickSort(array, 0, array.length-1);
        run++;
    }

    function partition(array, start, end){
        let pivot = array[end];
        let partitionIndex = start;
        
        for(let i = start; i < end; i++){
            if(array[i] <= pivot){
                swap(array, i, partitionIndex);
                partitionIndex++;
            }
        }

        swap(array, partitionIndex, end);
        //partitionIndex++;

        return partitionIndex;
    }

    function QuickSort(array, start, end){
        if(start < end){
            let partitionIndex = partition(array, start, end);
            QuickSort(array, start, partitionIndex-1);
            QuickSort(array, partitionIndex+1, end);
        }
    }

    return array;
}

console.log(doQuickSort([5,3,7,6,2,9]))
```